# How to negate a delegate?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, delegates

This is my code, heavily abbreviated for simplicity

```
Func<Product, bool> selector;
...
selector = p => p.IsNew;
...
if(negative) // not selector
  selector = x => !selector(x); // This is wrong (causes infinite loop)
  // How do you do negate it? The result should be p => !p.IsNew

...
IEnumerable<Product> products = MyContext.Products.Where(selector);
```

Comment: It looks like that you don't want it `infinite` so when do you want to stop/break it?

Comment: What do you mean by negating it?

Comment: @KingKing I don't understand what you mean<br>
@BoltClock On the example above, selector should be the same as `p => !p.IsNew`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with a helper method:

```
public static Predicate<T> Negate<T>(this Predicate<T> predicate) {
    return t => !predicate(t);
}
```

(or, replace `Predicate` with `Func<T, bool>`).

Then:

```
selector = selector.Negate();
```

Your stack overflow issue is pretty obvious; you're defining `selector` in terms of itself<sup>1</sup>. The helper method avoids that problem.

<sup>1</sup>: That is, this will clearly cause a stack overflow too:

```
public bool M() { return !M(); }
```

Believe it or not, you're doing exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a temporary Func:

```
if(negative)
{
    Func<Product, bool> tempSelector = selector;
    selector = x => !tempSelector(x);
}
```

This way `selector` no longer refers to itself.